# Docker Build seems to ignore an npm override in packages.json

Tags: docker, npm

There was a recent vulnerability found in the semver npm package. I have added a overrides section to my package.json file and doing an npm ci I can see under node_modules that only semver 7.5.3 is installed. npm audit also returns 0 vulnerabilities.

My docker file consists of this

```
FROM docker.io/library/node:16.20.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /build

COPY package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
RUN npm ci

COPY . ./
RUN npm run-script build

FROM docker.io/library/node:16.20.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /build/build public/

RUN npm i -g http-server

ENTRYPOINT [ "http-server" ]
```

However when I run docker build and check /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/package.json in the image I can see semver 7.3.7 is installed.

I'm struggling to understand why. I'm copying over my local package.json and package-lock.json and running an npm ci - which on my local machine results in a correct version of semver being installed, but not in my image.

both the image and my local machine are running npm 8.19.4
My package.json consists of this:

```
{
  "name": "mats-frontend-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Web Frontend UI",
  "dependencies": {
    "@essnextgen/ui-kit": "^0.7.3-alpha.55",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^3.3.6",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.17",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "jest-when": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.17.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-ga4": "^1.4.1",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "semver": "^7.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "test:ci": "CI=true react-scripts test --testResultsProcessor ./node_modules/jest-junit"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/frontend-web"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/jest-when": "^3.5.2",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.48",
    "@types/react-gtm-module": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^4.12.3",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest-junit": "^13.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.1",
    "msw": "^0.44.2",
    "node-talisman": "^1.29.10",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Was the `package-lock.json` that is copied to the image created before or after this version update?

Comment: the package-lock.json has not changed, so it was created before the override section was put in. However if I delete the node_modules folder in my local repo and do an npm ci it still only installs semver 7.5.3
So I was expecting the docker build to do the same. I guess Im struggling to understand why Im seeing a difference between whats happening in my local repo and whats happening with the docker build

Comment: Without knowing your local node version and the contents of package.json: Another guess would be that your local node version and the node version in your Dockerfile differ and this difference is due to version incompatibilities. Other than that, could you maybe try to re-build the image with an updated package-lock.json and/or use `npm install` instead of `npm ci`?

Comment: So I've just updated my post with my package.json and both local and image are using the same NPM version.
I've also removed package-lock.json from the copy command and done an npm install rather than an npm ci but still getting semver 3.7.3

Comment: Just figured out where its coming from - its the node:16.20.0-alpine image that I'm using

Comment: This means if you are using another node image the behavior is as intended?

Comment: I guess so - the vulnerable semver version was packaged with the node image. I've added RUN npm install -g npm@latest to my dockerfile and the vulnerability has gone :-)